# Properties of 1-Sphere in a linear normed space against a normed linear subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi i have a little problem in understanding the proof of the following theorem

If $N$ is a finite-dimensional proper subspace of normed
linear space $X$, there exists an element in the 1-sphere of $X$ whose distance
from $N$ is 1.

The proof basically takes a point $z$ on $X$ but not in $N$ so there exists a sequence $(n_k)$ of points in $N$ such that $||z - n_k|| \rightarrow d(z,N)$ (why?) ssince $N$ is finite dimensional and $n_k$ is bounded (why?) there exists a subsequence $v_k$ of $n_k$ which converges to some $n \in N$. Hence

$||z - n|| = \lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty} ||z - v_k|| = d(z,N) = d(z-n,N)$ (why $d(z,N) = d(z - n,N)$?).

The remaining part it is easy to understand...

Comment: When you say the "1-sphere" do you mean $\{x\in X: ||x||=1 \}$? This is properly called the unit sphere and generally a 1-sphere is just a circle.

Comment: $N$ is locally compact. The intersection of some closed $\epsilon$-ball around a point $m_0 \in N$ with $N$ is a closed and bounded set in a Euclidean space, and compact. Other than that, what is the source for this???? Meanwhile, the closed unit ball in a normed vector space is compact if and only if the space is finite dimensional

Comment: @PVAL it should be $\left\{ x \in X : ||x|| = 1 \right\}$

Comment: @Will Jagy. Is taken from a book.

Comment: author and title, please

Comment: https://books.google.it/books?id=wkBNXonCtPIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=unbounded+linear+operator&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAGoVChMI-6Hdtsz-xgIVZP5yCh3kFwNW#v=onepage&q=unbounded%20linear%20operator&f=false

Comment: evidently Lemma I.4.5 on page 14; in Seymour Goldberg, Unbounded Linear Operators, in case anyone wants to pursue this.

Comment: Yeah but i still don't get some point in that proof, especially some statement about the distance.

Comment: The definition of $d(x,M)$ for a point $x$ and a subset $M$ is I.2.1 on page 6. You need that, and various notions on pages 6-14.

Comment: Which notions? (i try to derive the equality for the distance)

Comment: for the equality... $ ||z - n|| = inf_{m \in N} ||z - n - m|| = d(z-n,N)$... i don't understand the existence and boundness of $n_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $z\not\in N$ and $N$ is closed, necessarily $\text{dist}(z,N)>0$ (if the distance is zero, it means that $z$ is in the closure of $N$).

By definition,
$$
\text{dist}(z,N)=\inf\{\|z-n\|:\ n\in N\}.
$$
So the numbers $\|z-n\|$ can be arbitrarily close to $\text{dist}(z,N)$, i.e. we are allowed to choose a sequence $\{n_k\}_k\subset N$ with 
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\|z-n_k\|=\text{dist}(z,N).
$$
As the sequence of numbers $\{\|z-n_k\|\}_k$ is convergent, it is bounded; there exists $c>0$ with $\|z-n_k\|\leq c$ for all $k$. 
Then
$$
\|n_k\|\leq\|z-n_k\|+\|z\|\leq c+\|z\|,
$$
which shows that the sequence $\{n_k\}$ is bounded. Since $N$ is finite-dimensional, closed and bounded sets are compact. So the sequence $\{n_k\}_k$ admits a convergent subsequence. If $n=\lim n_k\in N$ (remember that $N$ is closed, since it is finite-dimensional),
$$
\|z-n\|=\lim_k\|z-n_k\|=\text{dist}(z,N).
$$
The first equality is simply the continuity of the norm: using the reverse triangle inequality,
$$
\left|\,\|z-n\|-\|z-n_k\|\,\right|\leq\|(z-n)-(z-n_k)\|=\|n-n_k\|\to0.
$$

Finally, I don't see why it is needed, but $\text{dist}(z,N)=\text{dist}(z-n,N)$ because $n\in N$ and $N$ is a subspace:
$$
\text{dist}(z,N)=\inf\{\|z-r\|:\ r\in N\}=\inf\{\|z-n-r\|:\ r\in N\}=\text{dist}(z-n,N);
$$
as $N$ is a subspace, the elements $n-r$, as $r$ goes through all of $N$, describe all of $N$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... it starts to get clear (especially that i should keep with me a book of real analysis with sequence properties while i'm study). First question you said that by defintion of $dist(\cdot,\cdot)$ we can choose the sequence $n_k$ with that properties what are the logical steps that allow you to say that?

Comment: It's just the very basic fact that in any set of real numbers  with an infimum there is a sequence of elements of the set that converges to said infimum.

Comment: Is this the answer? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252756/existence-of-sequences-converging-to-sup-s-and-inf-s

Comment: Yes. Now, if you are not comfortable with sup, inf, and inequalities, you will have a hard time going on with functional analysis, since they are basic tools that are used a lot.

Comment: Slowly slowly... i will review all i need.